# How to change Dateformat

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

how to change date format of viewmodel's Datetime type property using clture. I am using below code for change the culture.

```
        CultureInfo newCulture = null;
        newCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";


        if (newCulture != null)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
        }
```

view's datetimePicker format has been changed but in viewmodel's property format not reflect. any help would be appreciated.

below is the property.

```
    private DateTime _fromDate = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime FromDate
    {
        get { return _fromDate; }
        set
        {
            _fromDate = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("FromDate");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have written your code in viewmodel constructer for setting culture and it is working my side.

Comment: are you using any thread or backgroundworker?

Comment: @J29:yes I am using backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check value of FromDate in backgroundworker this would be use same format of system.

//here would be your format as describe like "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
        {
        //and here would be system format
         };
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {

        };
```

possible solution: you have to change the culture inside the backgroundworker.